# a issue with attachment form

Tags: php, forms, conditional-statements, attachment

the following code works just fine, but when users submitting without any attachments the page gives error alert and nothing is happened, ther mast any condition that i'm missing, someone knows what i need to add?

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {

$allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt");

$files = array();
foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file) {
    $file_name = $file['name']; 
    $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $file['type'];
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
    $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
        die("File $file_name has the extensions $ext which is not allowed");
    }



    array_push($files, array('temp_name' => $temp_name, 'file_name' => $file_name));
}

// email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
$to = "dorozenman@gmail.com";
$from = $_POST['sender_email']; 
$subject ="בקשה להצעת עבודה מ" . $_POST['sender_name'] .' '. $_POST['sender_suname']; 
$message = 'שם: '. $_POST['sender_name'] . "\r\n" . 'שם משפחה: ' . $_POST['sender_suname'] . "\r\n" . 'תאריך לידה: ' . $_POST['sender_Bday'] . "\r\n" . 'עיסוק נוכחי: ' . $_POST['sender_work'] . "\r\n" . 'טלפון: ' . $_POST['sender_phone'] . "\r\n" . 'מייל: ' . $_POST['sender_email'] . "\r\n" . 'טקסט חופשי: ' . $_POST['sender_way'] ;
$headers = "From: $from";

// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

// preparing attachments
for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
$temp_name = $files[$x]['temp_name']; // temporary file location
$file_name = $files[$x]['file_name']; // filename
$file = fopen($temp_name,"rb");
$data = fread($file,filesize($temp_name));
fclose($file);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$file_name\"\n" . 
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$file_name\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}

// send

$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
if ($ok) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('הבקשה נשלחה! שיהיה לך בהצלחה!');
    top.window.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/gingereilat';
    </script>
    <?php }  else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    alert('שגיאה במערכת בצעו פעולה זאת מאוחר יותר או צרו קשר dorozenman@gmail.com');
    top.window.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/gingereilat';
</script>
<?php     
} 
  } 

  ?>
```

Comment: Altough I'm not completely sure but you might need to check `$_FILES` for the prepare attachments part aswell. Because if `$_FILES` is empty there is nothing to prepare and might cause the problem

Answer (score 2):

your whole code in following if clause

```
if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {
```

check where its applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the error messages!  That makes answering your question a lot easier.

Just reading the code, an obvious problem is var `$files` is only initialised inside the first `if` statement, but then you use it in the `for` loop.

Move the line `$files = array();` to the top of your script so it is always initialised as an empty array.